# NinJect Get Service is not returning an instance of the class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.0, ninject

I am working with MVC 4.0 & .net 4.0 and wish to use Ninject.

I have a static class, in which objects are created. I can NOT make the static calling class non-static!

I am trying to get an instance based on this binding

```
Bind<ClinicWebsite.ViewModels.ISelectionEngine>)
    .To<ClinicWebsite.ViewModels.Genric_SelectionEngine>();
```

in the static class I call:

```
ClinicWebsite.ViewModels.Generic_SelectionEngine myService =
    ClinicWebsite.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon.Kernel
        .GetService(typeof(ClinicWebsite.ViewModels.ISelectionEngine))
            as ClinicWebsite.ViewModels.Generic_SelectionEngine;
```

but when I examine "myservice" I get:

```
The name 'myservice' does not exist in the current context
```

What could I be doing wrong, or is there another way to explicitly create an instance with Ninject (again, cannot get rid of static calling class)

NinjectWebCommon

```
public static class NinjectWebCommon 
{
private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();
private static readonly StandardKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();

public static void Start() 
{
    DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
    DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
    bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
}
public static void Stop()
{
    bootstrapper.ShutDown();
}        
private static IKernel CreateKernel()
{         
    try
    {
        kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
            kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();
        //DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel));
        RegisterServices(kernel);

        return kernel;
    }
    catch
    {
        kernel.Dispose();
        throw;
    }
}
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    Bind<ClinicWebsite.ViewModels.ISelectionEngine>().To<ClinicWebsite.ViewModels.Generic_SelectionEngine>();
}
public static IKernel Kernel
{
    get
    {
        return kernel;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: How do you examine the variable? In debig? Are you sure that it is in the scope during evaluation?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
because this is in a static class I need to make"myservice" a static member of the class and then assign to it.